# Is a certain open subset of a connected space also connected?

Tags: general-topology

If $S$ is a connected space, what additional properties are required for $S$ to make the following a theorem: Suppose $p\in S$ is a cut point of $S$, and thus, there exist open $V\subset S$ and open $W\subset S$ satisfying $S-\{p\}=V\cup W$ and $V\cap W=\emptyset$. If $A\subset S$ is open and $p\in A$, then $A\cap V\not=\emptyset$ and $A\cap W\not=\emptyset$.

If this is not true in Euclidean space in particular, can you supply a simple counter example?

Comment: Suppose for a contradiction $A\cap W=\varnothing$. Then $V\cup \{p\}$ is open, being the union of the open sets $V$ and $A$, thus there is a partition of $S$ into disjoint open sets, namely $V\cup\{p\}$ and $W$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. For example, if $S$ is one dimensional Euclidean space, $p=0$, $V=(-\infty,0)$, and $W=(0,\infty)$, then I think $V\cup \{p\}=(-\infty,0]=(-\infty,p]$ is not open.

Comment: @LoBush: **If** you had an open $A$ containing $p$ that was disjoint from $W$, you would necessarily have $0\in A\subseteq(\leftarrow,0]$, and therefore $V\cup A=(\leftarrow,0]$, as the union of open sets, would be open. In fact it isn’t, which tells you that no such open $A$ can exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should hold in general, as the converse would violate the connectedness:

**Theorem** Let $S$ be any topological space and $p\in S$ a cut point decomposing $S\setminus \{p\}$ into disjoint nonempty open sets $V, W$. Then any open set $A$ containing $p$ must intersect both $V$ and $W$.

*Proof* If $A$ would not intersect one of these sets, say w.l.o.g. $V$, then $A\cup W$ and $V$ would be a nontrivial partition of $S$ into open (and hence also closed) sets: Indeed, if both $A$ and $W$ are disoint from $V$, so is their union. Furthermore, These two sets contain all of $S$ since $S = \{p\} \cup W \cup V \subseteq A \cup W \cup V$.
Also, they are clearly open.

Comment: Okay, now I see it! Both responses were needed for me to understand. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: @LoBush please mark this answer as accepted if you don't have any further questions. Otherwise, this question will still be categorized as „unanswered“.